# Child component width exceeds parent

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I've got a view based on CssLayout that has a predefined minimum width but can be expanded to fill entire screen.  This view, we'll call the parent, has child views in a list view.  Each child is an instance of the same class extending a HorizontalLayout.

I'm having several problems with layout.

First, the children are overlapping each other due to the encapsulating VerticalLayout giving each child a percentage of space instead of allowing them to space appropriately based on their heights.  The VerticalLayout is required because I need the parent to scroll when the list is larger than the parent.

Secondly, the children aren't sizing width to match the parent.  My attempts to fix result in either the child being so wide that a horizontal scroll is needed or the child is less wide than the parent and has extra space.

[image: Example of issues]

As seen in the image, the top two children are allowing extra space to the right.  The third child is overflowing the parent width causing the horizontal scroll.

How can I fix these two issues using Vaadin or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

After further testing, I was able to get close to the desired affect by switching the list child and the list parent to use CssLayout and setting the Height or Width after populating its content.